# What are some good practices for naming thousands of instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud

What are good practices when you have to come up with names for thousands of cloud instances for thousands of individual sites?

Answer (score 2):

If one performs a search on Google using a phrase such as "cloud instance naming best practice" one gets a raft of likely candidates for your question ... see for example:

https://blog.serverdensity.com/server-naming-conventions-and-best-practices/